# HTML5 <video> razor automatically adds closing tags to <source>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor, umbraco

I have the following code in my razor view which outputs the source tag:

`@Html.Raw("<source src=\"" + @mediaItem.Url + "\" type=\"" + @mediaType +"\">")`

It is looped x number of times depending on the presence of multiple file formats.
The issue being that the output returned is as following.

```
<video><source src="x.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="x.webm" type="video/webm"></source></source></video>
```

Which gives me an w3 validator error on stray end tags for 
I have no idea where or when the  tags are being closed or why.

Any ideas on how to stop it from closing the tags?

A bit more of the code, updated the source part to not use Html.Raw per suggestion, but still generates the same issue.

```html
<video id="frontCoverVideo" width="1920" height="450" playsinline autoplay loop muted controls>
  @foreach (var mediaItem in coverMedia)
  {
    <source src="@mediaItem.Url" type="@mediaItem.Type">
  }
 </video>
```

Comment: Can You provide a little bit more code responsible for this `video` tag?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I created this FIDDLE for you: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y8dVG4 and when you see the Source code generated, it's allright, no closed Tags. (*Edit*: Click on "View in Full Screen" in the Preview area and then examine the Source Code)

Comment: Thank you for the response, I see that this does not create the closing tags, which makes me assume that the issue lies within umbraco for some reason. I even tried simply writing it all out as plain html and it still added the extra closing tag.

Comment: Maybe it will then accept the self-closing Tag format `<source src="@mediaItem.Url" type="@mediaItem.Type" />`? (Mind the `/>` ending) (Updated my Answer if it helps)

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using `Html.Raw` in this case? It's not recommended to use it that way. I don't see any reason.

Assuming the Video Sources are a `List<VideoSource>` in your ViewModel.

```
<video>
@foreach(var source in Model.VideoSources)
{
    <source src="@source.Url" type="@source.MediaType" />
}
</video>
```

Any reason for not doing it the standard way?

**UPDATE**: Changed Code, added self-closing Source Tag to maybe fix issues lying within Umbraco

Comment: It was suggested as of another similar issue, been trying a lot of different approaches. Yours being close to my initial code.